# Code with Branches

Tags: python-3.x

```
def which_prize():
    return "Congratulations! You have won a [prize name]!"
    if Points ==0  or Points ==50:
       print("Congratulations! You have won a [wooden rabbit]!")
    elif Points ==0  or Points ==150:
       print("Congratulations! You have won a [no prize]!")
    elif Points==151  or Points ==180:
       print("Congratulations! You have won a [wafer-thin mint]!")
    elif Points ==181  or Points ==200:
       print("Congratulations! You have won a [penguin]!")

    else:
        print("Oh dear, no prize this time.")
```

The input to `which_prize()` will be the number of points (an integer). The function `which_prize()` should return the text "Congratulations! You have won a [prize name]!" with the prize name included if they have won a prize and the text "Oh dear, no prize this time." if there is no prize. As always, test your function to check whether it's performing correctly.

`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.`

Comment: How do you expect any of those statements to run after you `return` in the first line of your function?

Answer (score 1):

You are maybe mixing tabs and space.
Try to unindent your code and indent it again with only tabs (or spaces)

PS: How do you expect your code to be ran : the function ends just after the `return` statement.

Try :

```
def which_prize():
  if Points and Points <=50:
     return("Congratulations! You have won a [wooden rabbit]!")
  elif Points <= 150:
     return "Congratulations! You have won a [no prize]!")
  elif Points <= 180:
     return "Congratulations! You have won a [wafer-thin mint]!")
  elif Points > 180:
     return "Congratulations! You have won a [penguin]!")
  else:
      return "Oh dear, no prize this time."
```